# Expressing odds in japanese for horse racing

Tags: mathematics

I came across this line of dialogue:

> > 「もう少しで、**４－５だった**のに、途中で落馬しやがってよぉ...ありゃぁ絶対に八百長だぜぇ」
> >
> > "The odds were so close, at 4-5, but in the middle of things, the rider falls off his horse! It's gotta be rigged!"

I presume the character is referring to odds here, but when imagining the character speaking I do not know how to represent the hyphen (ー) verbally (or most maths symbols, really).

Some quick digging on [wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AA%E3%83%83%E3%82%BA) suggest that it would be represented as に, which would roughly match with english, but my japanese is not very good so I am asking here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not odds but the order of horse racing. 4-5 means that the horse of the number 4 finished first and the horse of the number 5 finished second.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. How would this be expressed in japanese?

Comment: Do you ask the reading? It is read just the number. 4-5 is read "yon go"

Comment: Yes, meant the reading, sorry for not being clear. Thank you